# Aadhar Authentication RD Service for fingerprint Android

Tags: java, android, android-fingerprint-api, aadhaar

I am developing app with Aadhaar payment which needs fingerprint authentication using Aadhaar UIDAI. but in market there are lot of fingerprint scanner devices. each device has their own rd service which return scan data(new format PID data). But I need one solution for many devices. I mean i don't want to keep track of  multiple RD service APk files with our application. whichever device is there it should return PID data of finger scan for Aadhaar authentication.

> Currently i have 3 device secugen, StarTek and Precision

```
1. Is it possible to install only one RD service for these three devices with application?

2. is it possible to have RD service .aar files in application itself?

3. one more thing can i use device(mobile's) fingerprint scanner for Aadhaar authentication?
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Based on the selection of device from the list, you can call the respective RD service using Intent. Most of them are available in the play store.If the App is available in the device it will allow you to capture or else it will redirect you to play store to install that application.So no need to install manually all the applications at once.
2. That .aar file need to be provided by Device vendor which is not possible.We can use RD Service from the device external apps only.
3. Mobile Finger print scanner are not Aadhaar specific, we cannot use that scanner for Aadhaar authentication.

Answer (score 1):

For 1. 
No , as per new guidelines each device needs to registered as well. 
The RD service is provided by the respective vendor [RD Serive for Morpho](https://rdserviceonline.com/)

For 3.
Mobiles finger print scanner is not supported yet, so no cant be used.

Also please check latest guidelines for Aadhaar, as new specs with VirtualId shall be available shortly.